# DRF Simple JWT does not log in user?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to use `simpleJWT` in my project. I have created a `CustomUser` in my profiles app and later added to `settings.py`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "profiles.User"
# django-allauth
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = (True)
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
#CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',

    ),
}
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER':
        'yogavidya.apps.profiles.api.serializers.PasswordResetSerializer',
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER':
        'yogavidya.apps.profiles.api.serializers.UserSerializer',
}
​
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED = True
LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE = False
​
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
 "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
 # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
 "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
 'yogavidya.emailbackend.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend',
)
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
​
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
​
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
​
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
​
    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',
​
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

When I try to login using Django REST Framework view, I get an answer but no user is logged in.

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTU5MDI2Njk2OCwianRpIjoiODhjN2FmOWZhZDBlNGIyYWFiYTRlMDA3YmVjNjY0YzciLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxfQ.YSluUaCU0r5WBlLmKmju1_HqrQjAxEDj5jONiv0U_mA",
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkwMTgwODY4LCJqdGkiOiJlNjI1ZjI5NjJjYTQ0OGM3YWQ2MWM2OTZhMWU5NWRkYyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.1A1ZTcxXRMQj5cBG631dwVeFQqG1FJVcKbjlrxRCcwE"
}
```

I have read the docs and in my opinion after placing credentials there must be a logged in user. How can I fix this behaviour?
Thanks

Comment: I can see you are getting access token, then what do you mean by `no user logged in` ?

Comment: I cannot get the user details @Md.TanvirRaihan. I will add my user module, none of the information is filled.

Comment: AFAK, simpleJWT doesn't include too many information in the JWT token, you have to include the claims by yourself https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research as Motakjug commented, I had to write a custom `View` and `Serializer` to get the `user` information in the `response`. If anyone also confused about this i will post my own answer:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super(MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, cls).get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['bio'] = user.bio
        return token


class ObtainTokenPairWithColorView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```